# stylesheets not loading for project checked in to TFS (via visual studio online)

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have an ASP.NET webforms project that I checked in to Visual Studio Online today. Unfortunately, now when I run the project my stylesheets no longer load.

I have checked all files from the solution into visual studio online. Should I have not checked in the .css files? Also, I have tried checking everything out then running the project to the same effect of the stylesheets not loading.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These two things are only coincidentally related. VSO has no effect on the ability of your project to load style sheets. And yes,'you should check them in.

Tye most likely issue is that the path to the style sheets has changed. If you moved the whole solution around then you may have to fix the paths if they are not relative..

Can you check:

1) that the css files exist and are where you think they should be

2) that the style reference points to the correct relative path of those files